# Decoding base64 string to xls file works fine for Windows but fails to open in Tablet

Tags: javascript, base64, xls

When converting base64 string to xls file and trying to open it, On windows desktop it prompts "The file format or extension do not match. Do you want to open it anyway?" Clicking on yes it opens the excel sheet just fine. But the same file doesn't open on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

I have tried keeping the same trust center settings. I have also transferred the same file to the tablet and tried opening still getting error "The spreadsheet maybe corrupted".

I'm using javascript, something like this:

```js
var base64String = ""; //this has the base64 string i have

//i have also tried a couple other mime types supported
var mime = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel";

var str = mime + ";base64," + base64String;
```

Expected is, it should open the same way as on Desktop in tablet but it is not. It is returning the error "This file type is unsupported by this version of Office".

Comment: You seem to be the encoding and a final comma on your mime var.  Eg. `data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,`

Comment: if you could take a look at the question now, i have edited it. It is not working still though.

Comment: What is your browser on the Tablet?

Comment: Chrome 75.0 version